# How do I check if a file exists in Java when the file path contains chinese words in Linux?

Tags: java, encoding, java-8

I run the code well when the file path is all English or Chines,but When my file path has both Chinese and English, the code result is false.In my window system,I try to encode the file path,and it runs well.But when I try to deploy it in the Linux system,It return false,the file path is:/home/file/GPRS核心.zip. How to fix my code?

```
//the first version
new File(fileName).exists()
//the second version
new File(new String(fullFileName.
            getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))).exists()
//the third version:return true in window and return false in linux
new File(new String(fullFileName.
            getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))).exists()
```

The linux encode is here:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: `new String(fullFileName. getBytes(charset))` is completely wrong, and will lead to data loss if Java's default charset does not match the specified charset . Just use `fullFileName` as-is, do not convert it. Your 1st version is correct, your 2nd and 3rd versions are wrong .

Comment: But 1nd still can not return true in Linux, some Chinese is OK,some is not ok.@RemyLebeau

Comment: it is Java's job, not your job, to convert a `String` to the OS's native charset when making system calls. If the 1st version is not working then there is a problem with how you are forming the `fileName`. Unicode is vast, you are probably just using the wrong Unicode characters in your `String`, or the wrong normalization for the characters. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating this issue in action.

Comment: fileName contains two parts, the prefix;
 `/home/file/`  is define in the server and it is always  the same ,and the last fileName is posted by the website, it is just a  string.When it return false,I return  the path to  the web,it is `/home/file/GPRS核心.zip`,And I login in the the system with WINSCP,it is really has a file called  GPRS核心.zip.

Comment: "*and the last fileName is posted by the website*" - like I said, you need to validate that it is using the proper Unicode characters and forms. "*it is just a string*" - a Unicode string depends on more than just the characters used, it also depends on HOW those characters are formed. Many Unicode characters have multiple forms. "*it is `/home/file/GPRS核心.zip` ... I login in the the system with WINSCP,it is really has a file called `GPRS核心.zip`*" - what do the *raw bytes* of those 2 strings look like?  I'm guessing the 2 byte representations don't exactly match, hence the `false` result.

Comment: Are you sure the website has the right to access `/home/file`? That’s a different process than the shell opened by an authorized scp and usually, processes spawned by a webserver get limited access rights for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a chinese system so cannot recreate that behaviour.

However I know if you run Windows configured for chinese, your filesystem should support unicode filenames. Java on it's own supports Unicode as it runs on UFT16. The problem you describe should not occur at all.

Therefore I strongly believe you introduced the problem by placing ISO_8859_1 encoding inbetween. Remove that stuff and you should be good.

In general do not use getBytes() - a character is not a byte.